# Stuck trying to use str in csv format as csv object in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a function in Python3 that returns a dictionary with values as str in csv format, something like this:

```
{server: csv_data,server2: csv_data2}
```

I want to take those values and access the data like you can do with a regular csv object, i.e:

```
for row in value:
    print(row['field'])
```

However when I try the attached code all the characters of the values are returned as single characters, ignoring the "," separating the values.
How could I reach the fields in the data? Is there a more pythonic aproach for this?

Note: csv_data is in binary so I understand that I must include .decode('utf-8') in order to use it properly.

```
for key,val in queryColectoras.items():
   val = val.decode('utf-8')
   for row in val:
      print(row)
```

Comment: Is the dict you get in the format shown or in a valid dict format: `{'server': 'csv_data','server2': 'csv_data2'}`?

Comment: PS. you do not need `for row in val:`

Comment: Also, what is your desired output? the fields? or the values? or both?

Comment: sorry, it's in a valid dict format. I think the dict part is working fine, the problem comes when I try to use csv_data content.
csv_data content looks like this:
`Header1,Header2,Header3
value1,value2,value3`
I'm trying to call those values with those headers, ie:
`print(variable['Header1'])
value1`

Comment: no worries, where is the part you're *trying to use csv_data content*?

Comment: `for row in val:
print(row)`
should print every row in val (the csv_data) but instead it prints every single letter as a row.

Comment: are these values `Header1,Header2,Header3 value1,value2,value3` in a string format? Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: try for `row in val.split():`?

Comment: using `val.split(',')` returns every entry as a row (headers and data), if I use `val.split('\n')` it returns the rows properly, but I still can't access a value directly. I'm trying to access it like you do with csv objects: `val['Header1']` would return `value1`